# InnoDB Write Log efficiency above 100%

Tags: innodb, mariadb, mariadb-10.1, mysqltuner

After running `mysqltuner.pl`, I get an Innodb write log efficiency way above 100 %. Why? What does it mean?
There is no specific reccomendation from `mysqltuner`.

DB is MariaDB 10.1.26 on Debian 9.x with 1 GB RAM.

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 64.0M/9.0M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 8.0M * 2/64.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (116110977 hits/ 116111816 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 4857.14% (10880 hits/ 224 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 11104 writes)
```

This is the configuration of InnoDb engine:

```
innodb                                                     ON
innodb-adaptive-flushing                                   TRUE
innodb-adaptive-flushing-lwm                               10
innodb-adaptive-hash-index                                 TRUE
innodb-adaptive-hash-index-partitions                      1
innodb-adaptive-max-sleep-delay                            150000
innodb-additional-mem-pool-size                            8388608
innodb-api-bk-commit-interval                              5
innodb-api-disable-rowlock                                 FALSE
innodb-api-enable-binlog                                   FALSE
innodb-api-enable-mdl                                      FALSE
innodb-api-trx-level                                       0
innodb-autoextend-increment                                64
innodb-autoinc-lock-mode                                   1
innodb-background-scrub-data-check-interval                3600
innodb-background-scrub-data-compressed                    FALSE
innodb-background-scrub-data-interval                      604800
innodb-background-scrub-data-uncompressed                  FALSE
innodb-buf-dump-status-frequency                           0
innodb-buffer-page                                         ON
innodb-buffer-page-lru                                     ON
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-at-shutdown                        FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-now                                FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-pct                                100
innodb-buffer-pool-filename                                ib_buffer_pool
innodb-buffer-pool-instances                               1
innodb-buffer-pool-load-abort                              FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-load-at-startup                         FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-load-now                                FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-populate                                FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-size                                    67108864
innodb-buffer-pool-stats                                   ON
innodb-change-buffer-max-size                              25
innodb-change-buffering                                    all
innodb-changed-pages                                       ON
innodb-checksum-algorithm                                  INNODB
innodb-checksums                                           TRUE
innodb-cleaner-lsn-age-factor                              HIGH_CHECKPOINT
innodb-cmp                                                 ON
innodb-cmp-per-index                                       ON
innodb-cmp-per-index-enabled                               FALSE
innodb-cmp-per-index-reset                                 ON
innodb-cmp-reset                                           ON
innodb-cmpmem                                              ON
innodb-cmpmem-reset                                        ON
innodb-commit-concurrency                                  0
innodb-compression-algorithm                               zlib
innodb-compression-failure-threshold-pct                   5
innodb-compression-level                                   6
innodb-compression-pad-pct-max                             50
innodb-concurrency-tickets                                 5000
innodb-corrupt-table-action                                assert
innodb-data-file-path                                      (No default value)
innodb-data-home-dir                                       (No default value)
innodb-default-encryption-key-id                           1
innodb-defragment                                          FALSE
innodb-defragment-fill-factor                              0.9
innodb-defragment-fill-factor-n-recs                       20
innodb-defragment-frequency                                40
innodb-defragment-n-pages                                  7
innodb-defragment-stats-accuracy                           0
innodb-disable-sort-file-cache                             FALSE
innodb-doublewrite                                         TRUE
innodb-empty-free-list-algorithm                           BACKOFF
innodb-encrypt-log                                         FALSE
innodb-encrypt-tables                                      OFF
innodb-encryption-rotate-key-age                           1
innodb-encryption-rotation-iops                            100
innodb-encryption-threads                                  0
innodb-fake-changes                                        FALSE
innodb-fast-shutdown                                       1
innodb-fatal-semaphore-wait-threshold                      600
innodb-file-format                                         Antelope
innodb-file-format-check                                   TRUE
innodb-file-format-max                                     Antelope
innodb-file-io-threads                                     4
innodb-file-per-table                                      TRUE
innodb-flush-log-at-timeout                                1
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit                             1
innodb-flush-method                                        (No default value)
innodb-flush-neighbors                                     1
innodb-flushing-avg-loops                                  30
innodb-force-load-corrupted                                FALSE
innodb-force-primary-key                                   FALSE
innodb-force-recovery                                      0
innodb-foreground-preflush                                 EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF
innodb-ft-aux-table                                        (No default value)
innodb-ft-being-deleted                                    ON
innodb-ft-cache-size                                       8000000
innodb-ft-config                                           ON
innodb-ft-default-stopword                                 ON
innodb-ft-deleted                                          ON
innodb-ft-enable-diag-print                                FALSE
innodb-ft-enable-stopword                                  TRUE
innodb-ft-index-cache                                      ON
innodb-ft-index-table                                      ON
innodb-ft-max-token-size                                   84
innodb-ft-min-token-size                                   3
innodb-ft-num-word-optimize                                2000
innodb-ft-result-cache-limit                               2000000000
innodb-ft-server-stopword-table                            (No default value)
innodb-ft-sort-pll-degree                                  2
innodb-ft-total-cache-size                                 640000000
innodb-ft-user-stopword-table                              (No default value)
innodb-idle-flush-pct                                      100
innodb-immediate-scrub-data-uncompressed                   FALSE
innodb-instrument-semaphores                               FALSE
innodb-io-capacity                                         200
innodb-io-capacity-max                                     18446744073709551615
innodb-kill-idle-transaction                               0
innodb-large-prefix                                        FALSE
innodb-lock-schedule-algorithm                             fcfs
innodb-lock-wait-timeout                                   50
innodb-lock-waits                                          ON
innodb-locking-fake-changes                                TRUE
innodb-locks                                               ON
innodb-locks-unsafe-for-binlog                             FALSE
innodb-log-arch-dir                                        (No default value)
innodb-log-arch-expire-sec                                 0
innodb-log-archive                                         FALSE
innodb-log-block-size                                      512
innodb-log-buffer-size                                     16777216
innodb-log-checksum-algorithm                              INNODB
innodb-log-compressed-pages                                TRUE
innodb-log-file-size                                       8388608
innodb-log-files-in-group                                  2
innodb-log-group-home-dir                                  (No default value)
innodb-lru-scan-depth                                      1024
innodb-max-bitmap-file-size                                104857600
innodb-max-changed-pages                                   1000000
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct                                 75
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct-lwm                             0.001
innodb-max-purge-lag                                       0
innodb-max-purge-lag-delay                                 0
innodb-metrics                                             ON
innodb-mirrored-log-groups                                 0
innodb-monitor-disable                                     (No default value)
innodb-monitor-enable                                      all
innodb-monitor-reset                                       (No default value)
innodb-monitor-reset-all                                   (No default value)
innodb-mtflush-threads                                     8
innodb-mutexes                                             ON
innodb-old-blocks-pct                                      37
innodb-old-blocks-time                                     1000
innodb-online-alter-log-max-size                           134217728
innodb-open-files                                          0
innodb-optimize-fulltext-only                              FALSE
innodb-page-size                                           16384
innodb-prefix-index-cluster-optimization                   FALSE
innodb-print-all-deadlocks                                 FALSE
innodb-purge-batch-size                                    300
innodb-purge-threads                                       1
innodb-random-read-ahead                                   FALSE
innodb-read-ahead-threshold                                56
innodb-read-io-threads                                     4
innodb-read-only                                           FALSE
innodb-replication-delay                                   0
innodb-rollback-on-timeout                                 FALSE
innodb-rollback-segments                                   128
innodb-sched-priority-cleaner                              19
innodb-scrub-log                                           FALSE
innodb-scrub-log-speed                                     256
innodb-show-locks-held                                     10
innodb-show-verbose-locks                                  0
innodb-simulate-comp-failures                              0
innodb-sort-buffer-size                                    1048576
innodb-spin-wait-delay                                     6
innodb-stats-auto-recalc                                   TRUE
innodb-stats-include-delete-marked                         FALSE
innodb-stats-method                                        nulls_equal
innodb-stats-modified-counter                              0
innodb-stats-on-metadata                                   FALSE
innodb-stats-persistent                                    TRUE
innodb-stats-persistent-sample-pages                       20
innodb-stats-sample-pages                                  8
innodb-stats-traditional                                   TRUE
innodb-stats-transient-sample-pages                        8
innodb-status-file                                         FALSE
innodb-status-output                                       FALSE
innodb-status-output-locks                                 FALSE
innodb-strict-mode                                         TRUE
innodb-support-xa                                          TRUE
innodb-sync-array-size                                     1
innodb-sync-spin-loops                                     30
innodb-sys-columns                                         ON
innodb-sys-datafiles                                       ON
innodb-sys-fields                                          ON
innodb-sys-foreign                                         ON
innodb-sys-foreign-cols                                    ON
innodb-sys-indexes                                         ON
innodb-sys-semaphore-waits                                 ON
innodb-sys-tables                                          ON
innodb-sys-tablespaces                                     ON
innodb-sys-tablestats                                      ON
innodb-table-locks                                         TRUE
innodb-tablespaces-encryption                              ON
innodb-tablespaces-scrubbing                               ON
innodb-thread-concurrency                                  0
innodb-thread-sleep-delay                                  10000
innodb-tmpdir                                              (No default value)
innodb-track-changed-pages                                 FALSE
innodb-trx                                                 ON
innodb-undo-directory                                      .
innodb-undo-logs                                           128
innodb-undo-tablespaces                                    0
innodb-use-atomic-writes                                   FALSE
innodb-use-fallocate                                       FALSE
innodb-use-global-flush-log-at-trx-commit                  TRUE
innodb-use-mtflush                                         FALSE
innodb-use-native-aio                                      TRUE
innodb-use-stacktrace                                      FALSE
innodb-use-sys-malloc                                      TRUE
innodb-use-trim                                            FALSE
innodb-write-io-threads                                    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be computed from

```
abs(Innodb_log_write_requests - Innodb_log_writes)  hits /
    Innodb_log_write_requests  total
```

where the values come from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.

"..._write_requests" are when InnoDB needs to write something to iblog on disk.  However, writes are buffered in the buffer_pool in hopes of collecting multiple things together a single write once ("..._writes").

Normally multiple "requests" would *eventually* result in a single "write".

The "abs()" is to hide negative numbers (more writes than requests).  Those don't make sense, but do seem to happen.

In the hundred servers I checked, none got more than 100%.

I would ignore the metric -- mysqltuner has issues, and InnoDB seems to be doing something extra with the number to make them less then useful for comparing *in this way*.

It's hard to get into any performance problems (that *tuning* can fix) when you have only 9MB of data+index.

Comment: That makes me think maybe it's something related to the fact that the server is mainly **read-only** and normally making very few (if any) writes to the database. Anyway good to know :-)

Comment: @Timido - "Very few writes" -- Then don't worry about write-related stats.

Comment: @RickJames does it make sense to have only 8 buffer pool instances when you have up to 48GB InnoDB data size? (max possible pool size is 42GB due to RAM Size).

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - The number of "instances" makes very little difference in performance -- perhaps only a few percent in a very busy system.  8 should be fine.  Someone suggests that 16 is the max that should be used.

Comment: Interesting, I ended up with 14 as there were 14 cores on the server. Will likely just leave it like that, the weird thing is that I noticed it seemed to be performing slightly better when it was on 21 instances, however I can't say whether that was due to a smaller InnoDB pool size as at then